# BadMethodCallException App\User::create() when seeding with zizaco

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having an error when seeding to the database using laravel 5.5 the error message is below and there is my users class and my seeder class. What is happening is that one record is being inserted at a time when calling db:seed but after the first call it says BadMethodException rest below

```
[BadMethodCallException]
Call to undefined method App\User::create()

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}

<?php

use App\User;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {       
        foreach (range(1, 100) as $index) {
            $faker = Faker::create();
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $faker->firstName . ' ' . $faker->lastName,
                'email' => $faker->email,
                'password' => bcrypt('secret')
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user model should extend

```
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
```

Or

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User
```

You are extending Eloquent

laravel/laravel repository: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: can you please show me how my users class should look like please

Comment: its a problem with using the entrust trait I know how to use the default user class but I'm using zizaco trait and it's not working in 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Your **User** class needs to extend to **Model** class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
     ...
}
```

**EDIT**

This is my User

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';


    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];


    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Im using this package and im having trouble with using User::create method https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust with laravel 5.5

Comment: You are extending Eloquent only.
You can do like

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;